# why don't loadash/underscore put the util method on array prototype?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

why the util methods didn't put the functions like `each`, `map` etc... on the array prototype?

the underscore `_` made my code a **bit** longer? shouldn't that be more neat?

or I missed something?

Comment: _underscore `_` made my code a lot longer?_ Not at all.

Comment: One reason: it's considered [generally bad practice](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/03/02/maintainable-javascript-dont-modify-objects-you-down-own/) to modify objects you don't own - meaning - what if another library wants to use the (native) method, but you've gone and modified it to behave differently than expected?

Comment: @Tushar, okay, how about a bit longer?

Comment: prototype.js did this back in the day. Then the javascript standard itself evolved to add new methods to arrays and objects, some of which clash with prototype.js. By the mid-2000s everyone realised that it was a bad idea. Today, modifying native objects is frowned upon so if you want your library to be popular you don't modify native objects. The ONE exception being libraries that provide implementations of proposed features for future (or not yet implemented) versions of javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to ask the original Underscore developers, but I can think of a couple of reasons:

#### Enumerability Issues

When Underscore was first released in 2009, the 5th edition JavaScript specification had only *just* come out and wasn't widely implemented. It was that spec which made it possible to add *non-enumerable* properties to an object; until then, adding properties to an object meant they showed up in `for-in` loops. This outputs "foo", for instance:

```
Array.prototype.foo = function() {};
for (var k in []) {
    console.log(k);
}
```

Example:

```js
Array.prototype.foo = function() {};
for (var k in []) {
    log(k);
}

function log(msg) {
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(msg));
    document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

As of ES5 it was possible to do this instead:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "foo", {
    value: function() { }
});
```

...which makes the `foo` property *non-enumerable* (doesn't show up in `for-in` loops and such), but again, that was brand-new when Underscore came out.

A lot of people use `for-in` to loop through arrays, even though they shouldn't without safeguards. So rather than break a huge amount of code, they decided not to extend built-in prototypes.

#### Conflicts

Even without the enumerability issue, extending built-in prototypes in a general-purpose library is not necessarily a good idea. Just about any name for a useful feature that Underscore could come up with might easily be used by the TC-39 committee in a future version of JavaScript, causing conflicts.

#### Clarity

Putting them on `_` makes it really clear that you're using Underscore, not a built-in feature of JavaScript arrays.

#### Utility to other types of objects

Many Underscore methods work on anything that's *array-like*, not just on arrays. Making the methods available on `_` instead of `Array.prototype` makes using them on non-arrays simpler. Consider [`_.pluck`](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck), for instance, which can be handy with DOM element collections (which are array-like, but not arrays):

```
var values = _.pluck(document.querySelectorAll("input"), "value");
```

Example:

```js
var values = _.pluck(document.querySelectorAll("input"), "value");

var p = document.createElement('p');
p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(values.join(", ")));
document.body.appendChild(p);
```

```html
<input type="text" value="one">
<input type="text" value="two">
<input type="text" value="three">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```